# How to encrypt .env file

Tags: php, laravel

When we put laravel project to localhost. Anyone can view our project .env file and they can view our database password `DB_USERNAME=user_name` and `DB_PASSWORD=password` how can we encrypt it?

I Need Solution to encrypt the file or data in it

NO need of blocking the file with following code

## Disable index view

`Options -Indexes`

## Hide a specific file

```
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: we already explained the issue here and why you have a bad setup; the last time you asked this same question ... configure your server correctly instead of trying to create some work around for a problem that shouldn't exist   `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are setting the document root of your project on the wrong directory.

I think, tell me if i'm wrong, you are setting it to `/path/to/your_project` instead of `/path/to/your_project/public`. This would explain why you need to encrypt your `.env`, because it would indeed be publicly accessible.

If that's the case, then the solution is pretty simple: fix your document root directory and set it to `/path/to/your_project/public`.

*ps: i did this mistake many years ago, it works like a charm if you only rename `server.php` to `index.php`... everyone was a beginner at some point ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Imo it would be useless to do so.

**Why?**

Because if someone has access to your source code they can do what ever they want. Even if you encrypt it (not to mention that's a pretty big hassle itself, because you have to encrypt and then decrypt every variable before using them), the `APP_KEY` variable that is used to store a key for encryption and decryption will still be exposed. So it will be a hassle for no reason.

*P.s: Like you said in your question, your source is at localhost, I'm not sure why you want to do it? And what you want to achieve by doing it!*

Comment: As per our company policy , they need to encrypt the file in the project file                      
                                                                                                                                           
Note: share any solution related to encrypting the file

Comment: Well that's strange, I've never heard anything like this. Anyways if you need to implement encryption/decryption, you need to start reading about it. There you go, a start point from [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption).

Comment: You're `.env` file is like a bunch of keys, that is used to start a car. You want to put your keys in a locker (for safety) and the key that locks your locker is still out there in your room. If you allowed someone in your room, they have access to your locker key and ultimately your car keys.

Answer (score 0):

The .env file is like a private key, you shouldn't post it publicly, and only share it with people you trust. Another option is to post only the non-sensitive parts publicly, and share private info like passwords and database names with people you trust.

Comment: In addition, i would add this is the purpose of `.env.example`